How to use both group by and order by with criteria builder
I have a train service application
I have a class called Booking, it also has Product as a list on it.
Product has TrainBooking and TrainBooking has TrainJourney as a list on it.
I use the criteria builder to fetch bookings.
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<Booking> bookingRoot = query.from(Booking.class);

    initializeJoins(bookingRoot);

    Order orderParam = getOrderParam(request, cb, bookingRoot);

    Fetch<Booking, Product> productFetch = bookingRoot.fetch("products", JoinType.LEFT);
    Fetch<Product, TrainBooking> trainBookingFetch = productFetch.fetch("trainBooking", JoinType.LEFT);
    productFetch.fetch("provider", JoinType.LEFT);
    Fetch<TrainBooking, TrainJourney> trainJourneyFetch = trainBookingFetch.fetch("trainJourneys", JoinType.LEFT);
    trainJourneyFetch.fetch("journey", JoinType.LEFT);

    query.multiselect(bookingRoot, journeyJoin.get(DEP_DATE_STR))
        .orderBy(orderParam)
        .distinct(true)
        .where(createPredicates(request, otaUser, cb, bookingRoot));

I use the distinct keyword here but it fetches some duplicate bookings. I want to use groupBy by bookingId and order by departure date. I could not find any way to use both order by and group by in the criteria builder for my case. Do you know how I can handle this?

You can call groupBy like
.groupBy(bookingRoot.get("bookingId"));

and also call orderBy. If it does not work for you, then it's likely that the query generated failed due to a logical error. See this about how to log queries.
Now, if you group by bookingId and then want to order by something, then let's not forget that you are no longer working with the initial relation by the time your order by is being executed, but a grouped relation, so you can only order by the field(s) you grouped by or aggregates of other fields. So if you tried to order by a field which you did not group by, then you get a problem of inconsistency.
Thing about this example:
a b
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 2
2 1

now, let's consider you have a query like this:
select a, sum(b)
from t
group by a

you get a result of two records, the first has 1 as the value of a, the second has 2, whereas both have 6 as the sum of b, because I was not creative-enough to define values that would yield different sums in the two groups.
Now, let's think about how could we order this query by b. Since we have two groups, each has 3 different values for b, sorting by b is too vague and it's difficult to make any sense of it, because there are b values of 1, 2, 3 in each group, so which b would we like to order by with? It makes no sense at all. We could order by min(b) or max(b) or avg(b), that is, we would aggregate by b, that is, with the help of some group functions, we compute a synthesis of the column for the group where it is involved and then we could order by this value. Or, if we wanted b to be an aggregate field, that's achievable too, as long as we group by b too.
So when you have a conflict between group by and order by, the most likely reason for it is that you want to order by a nonaggregated field.
